How to set Visual Studio Code Python Interpreter to a Python Virtual Environment in a Parent Directory?
I have a python virtual environment in /Documents and a project in /Documents/Code/Python/example. I want to use this venv in my project but I can't get the vs code python interpreter to recognize that the venv in /Documents is a venv.
I tried to use set the interpreter path by using the "Find..." button to manually select /Documents/.venv/bin/python with the finder. However, it is recognizing it as something other than a virtual environment as it looks different when compared to a venv in the same directory as the project. Here is the output below:
2024-08-08 16:53:55.325 [info] Discover tests for workspace name: example - uri: /Users/varun/Documents/Code/Python/example
2024-08-08 16:53:55.326 [info] Python interpreter path: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.12/3.12.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3.12

How it looks when venv is in a parent directory
How it looks when venv is in same directory
I suspect that it is because /Documents/.venv/bin/python is referencing a "faulty" version of python (I'm not sure though). I'm able to activate and use the venv from the terminal to run the code but with vs code not recognizing the venv it isn't giving me any autofill suggestions. Please let me know if you need more info, thanks.

seems similar and related to Can we create a venv for python and use that venv in other folders in VSCode, Windows 10?

I have a different problem from that. I am able to activate the venv and run the code normally using the venv from the parent folder; however, my problem is that visual studio code is not recognizing my venv in the editor meaning it isn't giving any autofill suggestions and it's saying that certain modules are not found.

it could be that vscode didn't find the correct interpreter path. Are you creating a virtual environment using the command python -m venv myvenv? Or try restarting vscode after clearing the cache and then opening it up to create a new virtual environment. If you still can't recognize it, you can set the path to the virtual environment in the .vscode/settings.json file. Add "python.pythonPath":"path/to/your/project/venv/bin/python" and  "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "path/to/your/venv/bin/python". See if that solves the problem.

Clearing the cache of the python extension and reloading vs code worked for me. Thanks!
